# Find elements in a vector which lie within specified ranges

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of integer elements in sorted. An example is given below:

```
vector<int> A ={3,4,5,9,20,71,89,92,100,103,109,110,121,172,189,194,198};
```

Now given the following "start" and "end" ranges I want to find out which elements of vector A fall into the start and end ranges.

```
int startA=4; int endA=8;
int startB=20; int endB=99;
int startA=120; int endC=195;
```

For example,

```
elements lying in range startA and startB are: {4,5}
elements lying in range startA and startB are: {20,71,89,92}
elements lying in range startC and startC are: {121,172,189,194}
```

One way to do this is to iterate over all elements of "A" and check whether they lie between the specified ranges. Is there some other more efficient way to find out the elements in the vector satisfying a given range

Comment: have you tried using `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`?

Answer (score 6):

If the vector is sorted all you need to do is to use dedicated functions to find your start range iterator and end range iterator - `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`. Eg.:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> A ={3,4,5,9,20,71,89,92,100,103,109,110,121,172,189,194,198};
   auto start = std::lower_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), 4);
   auto end = std::upper_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), 8);
   for (auto it = start; it != end; it++) {
      std::cout << *it << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

//or the C++1z version (works in VS2015u3)
int main() {
   std::vector<int> A ={3,4,5,9,20,71,89,92,100,103,109,110,121,172,189,194,198};
   std::copy(std::lower_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), 4),
             std::upper_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), 8),
             std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This however will work only if `startX <= endX` so you may want to test the appropriate condition before running it with arbitrary numbers...

Searching bound iterators using `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` will cost `O(log(N))` however it has to be stated that iterating through the range of elements in average case is `O(N)` and the range may contain all the elements in your vector...

Comment: When a stream is closed, it is flushed by iostreams. The final endl can safely by replaced with '\n'

Comment: @DavidThomas true, but I think Warty intended to prepare the code to be extracted to a standalone function. In this context flushing would be a good choice.

Comment: Sorry for necroing this, but couldn't you potentially narrow the search area by using the iterator returned by std::lower_bound() as the first parameter in std::upper_bound()? Just a thought...

Answer (score 5):

> One way to do this is to iterate over all elements of "A" and check whether they lie between the specified ranges. Is there some other more efficient way to find out the elements in the vector satisfying a given range

If the vector is sorted, as you have shown it to be, you can use binary search to locate the index of the element that is higher than the lower value of the range and index of element that is lower than the higher value of the range.

That will make your search O(log(N)).

You can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), which requires the container to be partially ordered, which is true in your case.

If the vector is not sorted, linear iteration is the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think is to apply modified binary search twice and find two indices in the vector arr and then print all items in between this range . Time complexity will be O(log n).
A modified form of binary search looks like:(PS its for arrays, also applicable for vector):

```
int binary_search(int *arr,int start,int end,int key)
{
    if(start==end)
    {
        if(arr[start]==key){return start+1;}
        else if(arr[start]>key&&arr[start-1]<=key){return start;}
        else return 0;
    }
    int mid=(start+end)/2;
    if(arr[mid]>key && arr[mid-1]<=key)return mid;
    else if(arr[mid]>key)return binary_search(arr,start,mid-1,key);
    else return binary_search(arr,mid+1,end,key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If range of integers of vector A is not wide, bitmap is worth the consideration. 
Let's assume all integers of A are positive and are in between 0 ... 1024, the bitmap can be built with:

```
#include <bitset>
// ...
// If fixed size is not an option
// consider vector<bool> or boost::dynamic_bitset
std::bitset<1024> bitmap;
for(auto i : A)
  bitmap.set(i);
```

That takes N iterations to set bits, and N/8 for storing bits. With the bitmap, one can match elements as follows:

```
std::vector<int> result;
for(auto i = startA; i < endA; ++i) {
  if (bitmap[i]) result.emplace_back(i);
}
```

Hence speed of the matching depends on size of range rather than N. This solution should be attractive when you have many limited ranges to match.